# Iterating through, and editing a dataframe, using outputs from a collision detector's neighbor-list

Tags: python, pandas

Say the beginning dataframe is this:

```
   System  Sizes       X     Y  Z
0       1      1     1.0     0  0
1       1      2     2.4     0  0
2       1      3    50.0    50  0
3       3    100   500.0   500  0
4       3    100   501.0   501  0
5       3    100   505.0   506  0
6       3    100  1000.0  1000  0
7       3    100  1001.0  1001  0
8       3    100  1005.0  1005  0
```

The "Sizes" refer to units of volume of a sphere. Each sphere is assigned a system in which to be, and also X, Y & Z center coordinates.

If spheres in the same system, have a volume and coordinates, such that their radii overlap the distance between them, the spheres "collide". In this case, one sphere takes on all the units of volume of the colliding spheres, and the rest are assigned volume 0.

The output would be:

```
   System  Sizes       X     Y  Z
0       1    3.0     1.0     0  0
1       1    0.0     2.4     0  0
2       1    3.0    50.0    50  0
3       3  200.0   500.0   500  0
4       3    0.0   501.0   501  0
5       3  100.0   505.0   506  0
6       3  300.0  1000.0  1000  0
7       3    0.0  1001.0  1001  0
8       3    0.0  1005.0  1005  0
```

What must be iterated through are a) the systems, and b) the groups of colliding spheres within each systems. Plus, c) the collision detector has to be used optimally.

This code uses Atomic Simulation Environment, and the code is a work-around for the rigidity in how it outputs neighbor-lists (https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/neighborlist.html)

Spheres may be called atoms, because the library used treats them as such.

The beginning dataframe is saved as "experimental_data".

The code I have so far, which gives the right results, is:

```
def adjust_size_for_neighbors(experimental_data):

    practical_experimental_data = experimental_data.copy()        
    #This is the dataframe I want outputted
    
    list_of_systems = (experimental_data["System"].unique().tolist())
    #I'm using a list to iterate through the unique systems
    
    for system in list_of_systems:
       
        system_experimental_data = experimental_data.loc[experimental_data['System'] == system]
        #filter for only the data in the system

        system_experimental_data =system_experimental_data[system_experimental_data['Sizes'] !=0]
        #filtering out zero sizes

        positions = ((system_experimental_data[["X", "Y", "Z"]]).values )
        #This is the format Atomic Simulation Environment, the library I'm going to use for the collision detector, wants the coordinates

        digit = len(system_experimental_data)
        string = 'N' + str(digit)
        atoms = Atoms(string, positions)
        #ASE wants the first input for atoms, to be a a letter representing the atom you're using, and a number for how many there are. 
        #For example, N7 would be 7 Nitrogen atoms. From my understanding, the picked atom is arbitrary for the calculations.
        #The Atoms object is a collection of atoms.
        #Documentation for Atoms here https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/atoms.html

        radii = ((3/4)*(1/math.pi) * ((system_experimental_data[["Sizes"]]).values) )**(1/3)
        #Calculating the radii based on the volumes, going backwards from V = (4/3)(Pi)(r^3)
        #The output is a list of one-element lists

        radii = radii.reshape(len(radii))
        #Creating a list out of a list of lists
        
        nl = NeighborList(radii, self_interaction=True, bothways = True)
        #self_interaction=True  means count an atom as interacting as itself
        #bothways=True means if atom 1 is counted as neighboring atom 2, when the code gets to atom 2, still count it as neighboring atom 1.

        nl.update(atoms)

        second_system_experimental_data = system_experimental_data.copy()
        #making a new dataframe for later

        indices_list = []
        #This will turn out to be a list of lists, with each list having the indices of group of colliding atoms

        for i in range(len(system_experimental_data)):
        #iterating through the atoms

            indices,offsets = nl.get_neighbors(i)
            indices_list.append(indices)

            #Because self_interaction = True and bothways = True:
            #For system 1, for example:
            # i = 0 gives indices = [0,1,0]
            # i = 1 gives indices = [1,0,1]
            # i = 3 gives indices = [2,2]


        #What is needed is, for example:
        #[[a,b],[b,c],[d,e],[e,f]] = [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]
        #this comes up in system 3
        #for that, I have the following code

        def dfs(node,index):

            taken[index]=True
            ret=node
            for i,item in enumerate(indices_list):
                if not taken[i] and not ret.isdisjoint(item):
                   ret.update(dfs(item,i))
           return ret

        def merge_all(indices_list):
            ret=[]
            for i,node in enumerate(indices_list):
                if not taken[i]:
                    ret.append(list(dfs(node,i)))
           return ret

        #These 2 functions are actually defined before the very first for loop begins, but they're here for the continuity of the question

        taken=[False]*len(indices_list)
        indices_list=[set(elem) for elem in indices_list]
        list_of_lists = (merge_all(indices_list))

        #list_of_lists =
        # [[0,1],[2]] for system 1
        # [[0,1],[2], [3,4,5] for system 3
        #This is all a work-around for the rigidity of the output for "indices"

        sizes_data_frame = system_experimental_data[["Sizes"]] * 1
        second_sizes_data_frame = second_system_experimental_data["Sizes"] * 1
        #Isolate the Sizes column from both the dataframes into their own dataframes

        if max([len(i) for i in list_of_lists])!=1:
        #the elements that are lists containing only one element are not of interest, ie, [0,1] is of interest, [2] isn't.
            for a_list in list_of_lists:
                (second_sizes_data_frame.iloc[a_list]) = 0  
                #Setting all the "Sizes" values in the dataframe rows that were found to neighbor each other in my copy dataframe to 0.
         
                first_index = a_list[0]
                #Picking out the first atom to neighbor the rest, because only one is needed

                    
                (second_sizes_data_frame.iloc[first_index]) = ((sum((sizes_data_frame.iloc[a_list]).values))[0]) 
                #Of all the rows whose "Sizes" value were set to 0, the first one is being set to the sum of the "Sizes" values belonging to those rows initially.

        second_system_experimental_data["Sizes"] = second_sizes_data_frame
        #put this new "Sizes" column back into the copy dataframe for the system

        practical_experimental_data.update(second_system_experimental_data)
        #Update the dataframe that is the output of the whole process to have the adjusted "Sizes"

    return(practical_experimental_data)
```

Comment: "The code I have so far" and does it produce the correct results? Is there more to your program than just this function?

Comment: Yes, it does produce the correct results. And no, there isn't more to the program than just this function.

Comment: Good! Welcome to Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## overwrite builtin modules

You use the variable name `string`, which can overwrite the builtin `string` module. I would use the variable name `atom_name` or something.

## f-strings

With `f-strings` you can also do this `atom_name inline`: `atoms = Atoms(f"N{len(system_experimental_data)}", positions)`

## list comprehension

Instead of instantiating a `list`, and then appending to it, a list comprehension can be clearer:

```
indices_list = [nl.get_neighbors(i)[0] for i in range(len(system_experimental_data))]
```

## pandas errors

There are a few things that can be done easier

```
radii = ((3/4)*(1/math.pi) * ((system_experimental_data[["Sizes"]]).values) 
radii = radii.reshape(len(radii))
```

can be `((3/4)*(1/math.pi) * ((system_experimental_data["Sizes"]).values)`

There is no reason to do the `tolist` in `(practical_experimental_data["System"].unique().tolist())`

## cluster indices

Your method to find the indices is quite convoluted. The inner methods also use and change nonlocal scope variables (`taken`) which should be passed in as argument

I think it would be easier to do this with a Series:

```
clusters = pd.Series(range(len(system_experimental_data)))
for indices in indices_list:
    cluster= clusters [indices]
    changed_indices = cluster[cluster.index != cluster]
    if changed_indices.empty:
        clusters[indices] = indices.min()
    else:
        clusters[indices] = changed_indices.min()
```

This makes use of the pandas indexing. The crux is using `neighbourhood[neighbourhood.index != neighbourhood]` to check for previous 'collisions'

For system 3, this is the result:

> ```
> 0    0
> 1    0
> 2    2
> 3    3
> 4    3
> 5    3
> dtype: int64
> ```

## Split of functions

Your code is quite long. This can be made more readable by splitting of smaller parts. One easy part to split off, is starting from the data for one system, find the clusters:

```
def find_clusters(system_data):
    """Searches for neigbours in a system
    
    Expects a DataFrame with 
    - ["X", "Y", "Z"] columns for the position
    - a "Sizes" column for the volume
    
    Returns a Series with the index of the input as index, and a label for the cluster
    
    """
    positions = (system_data[["X", "Y", "Z"]]).values
    #This is the format Atomic Simulation Environment, the library I'm going to use for the collision detector, wants the coordinates
    atoms = ase.Atoms(f"N{len(system_data)}", positions)
    
    radii = ((3/4)*(1/math.pi) * ((system_data["Sizes"]).values))**(1/3)
    #Calculating the radii based on the volumes, going backwards from V = (4/3)(Pi)(r^3)
    #The output is a list of one-element lists
    nl = NeighborList(radii, self_interaction=True, bothways = True)
    nl.update(atoms) # this is the way the ase API works
    
    clusters = pd.Series(range(len(system_data)))
    
    for i in range(len(system_data)):
        indices, _ = nl.get_neighbors(i)
        cluster = clusters[indices]
        changed_indices = cluster[cluster.index != cluster]
        if changed_indices.empty:
            clusters[indices] = indices.min()
        else:
            clusters[indices] = changed_indices.min()
            
    return pd.Series(clusters.values, index=system_data.index)
```

This might be made more efficient for larger systems by skipping indices which have been altered already, but that might give rise to certain edge cases.

This is a method with a docstring explaining what the method expects, and what it will return. This method can also be easily tested in isolation

## `groupby`

Instead of iterating over the unique values, pandas has its `groupby` functionality.

Since we have the existing method to find the neighbourhoods, we can do

```
clusters = df.groupby("System", group_keys=False).apply(find_clusters)
```

That gives us:

> ```
> 0    0
> 1    0
> 2    2
> 3    0
> 4    0
> 5    2
> 6    3
> 7    3
> 8    3
> dtype: int64
> ```

The sum of each cluster is then as easy as `df.groupby(["System", clusters])["Sizes"].sum()`

```
System   
1       0      3
        2      3
3       0    200
        2    100
        3    300
Name: Sizes, dtype: int64
```

Getting the indices for these can be done with:    `df.reset_index().groupby(["System", clusters])["index"].first()`

```
System   
1       0    0
        2    2
3       0    3
        2    5
        3    6
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

This can be combined :    `df.reset_index().groupby(["System", clusters]).agg({"Sizes": "sum", "index": "first"})`

> ```
> System        Sizes   index
> 1 0   3   0
> 1 2   3   2
> 3 0   200 3
> 3 2   100 5
> 3 3   300 6
> ```

We can transform this to the new `Sizes` column: `result.set_index("index").reindex(df.index).fillna(0)`

## putting it together

With some pandas reindex magic and a fluent style, The end result is as simple as:

```
def adjust_size_for_neighbors(experimental_data):
    clusters = (
        experimental_data.query("Sizes != 0")
        .groupby("System", group_keys=False)
        .apply(find_clusters)
    )

    grouped_sizes = (
        experimental_data.reset_index()
        .groupby(["System", clusters])
        .agg({"Sizes": "sum", "index": "first"})
        .set_index("index")
        .reindex(experimental_data.index)
        .fillna(0)
    )
    return experimental_data.assign(grouped_sizes=grouped_sizes)
```

I've picked `grouped_sizes` as name for the new column. If you want to keep the original column name, you can do `return experimental_data.assign(Sizes=grouped_sizes)`

Answer (score 3):

Good submission, and it looks like you're already following several common best practices, but here are some suggestions for improvement on top of that.

- PEP8: spaces around `=`, operators, after commas, etc., there are several violations in this code w.r.t. spacing. An excellent tool for automatically applying PEP8 is called Black, [you can see a demo of it on your code snippet here](https://black.now.sh/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4BVoB7ZdAD2IimZxl1N_WlbvK5V8IreJS0IKPTToj1-Pe3gnXSW2I_6_uLII1n2BgXxRR3LYqxjqAgGytDjLJY7OGEcuivXwbZQ8eImItVDyr0ua-qobJTCI5mpSkpW_mUbuT5aeeuVxqaugnxSA5kJOXj9D5x72ir9VNNhPMpEh-_MwMNgwmDpi4Dx5BTgfQQc-VWSBZkOgnPdXSgCBH3Z6uh5bWnmmrETeTVFdFwYdlUPcw-zX9wLDlTzx4DrRApCximXIswGDff8Tw7e5CEJIiHlleFpKj8YTbb9nyKf34Wzc3DkJ4gCyM5cbb59ClxIh4KfivDu2UF0qq8cg4898IaB1iDQoBK2KLK_3OEFz3o0BbCPbAOjqCoZhoeWayaeZnimEBCzg8tedAwoiNs_kxJVRUoVwQOgRI5KQ0TynM0HSfBurtS7Pk3chkVy1BvNgza9idTpYBgryCDCse91sLoeFiHCd4c7gkjBE6yaVckxp08tlnUYL3_5XvEidrPNwhlcsyN8L8WsPo4F9twIVfogOy0tV2nVR3j0cE19r4DYVr6_nHiu9OE2FO9Ty0zLT5Yf102JYAljBphktpW2h_KXybZG_lEOdM-e90ls-KwuwmFrFKXHiRoE3E8A2ObZld7KItEI-BAq0M__jm3rrQa0_Xv14qigoM7iYcZ-_v_7iurOAUbkoNB7Ypqv03i3AuyudYNeYKjnykbbRGqyOfxF7w5T-GvbvvX1AG3g33KOVkptaL2_KarAXki_mZ002gSesN09L2jwLYGhkyxdkWCqVzK3dZtdFtfLe_NnTBXI0yYcG4YFDohSeg4DfsF9ro7dt1CR3SaNKe6-17EM-ZFWOyX_C6mGB8DgTfERz2VfZc3lDai467YU1ItsFJSHMgxOCi5b-TbHEuZR5yJttFoBD6SiF1jUbQy0Z2aJSL3KAMLWi24xOCRESTGRX_zG6fHyi6omUHTNVJR3cRBQZJ07tMk5uAWfKkAimo4gWnTprPZAil50u0VuKOrzpIBa4ZZgsaczOoZdrhUqcjJTLDuIiq5Co25aOQGv_Mz36CYVHGF3P4FqAUyF62dXqkjGC2If26nFrYaD1oSb6J3b-0mGd2hbkb3e9YTdBZ-JCguvZRST9LytQ1O5oqkE2QBqC_rYW6SOweLtNrxnIeOnE7DQPS9LQl7orf-4d46_cpYQngBXNY_7UPcRhj3zENx310DTl9WMejc04qWQBygQ5UruRcRfKODUGT27NFnjNdz-hZIS_t79HvkCW9Ep465tq21pjzEcXB5xQ5QtFvcmDiDr9O3-dmMxcfHLlym9cLDQKcofcC3-c6oE23JDV8VzeQ2UBu-6ALLpNU-Ro86XFWFvHh04Md0OZkMh7VhTu3bfbdgDflv9PrI6a8LFyZDNI5slpcUHb-GbhTsiRrp-S25ezMNpJ9-ch9avm1nFi2kwe_c5t8tR4Sn5zAn8c9EZeT0UY8xVnE5uPZ5GJaJ10TjOuygHMvJUpgApO6jGLdut_3jHXhuHImeSGS_5E8n9q1DXKiX8o3xjqtPCckKTxIwo6p9OSm8JWJw4-fmS_Brk4C9OEDFnkXzRf6oXsCY2yPIfEbfAG4KBqUjAu7VXF2TU-sQkEuVwg9hwXHHn86h5VxqqdKhlA44QcsXaWE5kHEc9c1wUAUYCFWbMuOkSpk8yv3uqLcMKbWvxzUgRaYLYPDvNJz3yfU4umBKnWBcm1-__SvDkzBcfCYc_srJr8z4sk_K0XaGEbV8ZJHMQWfSsZglNs7z5YEtsNBU4mAwYCxUBqK2RLFAxh53_4YS9gy9cgUv9nV6iNDnsjk7d8omPA41f9JpEmm-lDm-kphe6MuxjnIaR3uH3k8MC5Dbl9scoZMKHrNTEW14KkriWeiqnKGWi9RMqvzWjlSe99395dJNUPVje8q-YgQM-uw5faL3Mf_3gJySRzH9mWtgc7hOzEBuoZtalSpxAtEozyaANLGry-sqA-6Hy4wpNoRvmK-9c6BSQugPupRvu4F1hJL-JUsn8xtH7BCNy2h2oDWd7FK4PbNDRE4PkoQbh52_40bT2r2HR8uleMhipg7K0oij-pocrAqhAVYYEs0MFx6OoQy4aNMSpeROCiJvbCBW8_J-NJGgN9o2JbH83lBYO0RWkbUsrDHi45Rw9BvLDzklNm9iUadqZF4H0rHyrTXg-w8b3tao_SNHH-Y3TbmAz-hP4r-UghapXz59zvN-vKWlE4SKAQZ_dUyE3j21d6dRs2AaPgw1n7Dy7l_XMyhd8BNFQk24IoQ127SiPLqnFcebe-XOJMYP6RYhOAf43dQqytfn8kmfKY9N2ojg4NRuuhvDujgUzEMI4sVkEJDunzxZVxAX9K32PMbmv7z8mEZqq8mhAEx-FqSNWDsPqz6BHRE-YGbyixy7xr0uGMgkNiw0JYUNil8Jat-0Z6i3wZAzz6_OAGwLM9lBXkOLPGSDxIRTmdy4Dz8nxBxkwgxjwnP2U1FSW9mvD7qa2S3FjZhLyX8TtAQk4zlmReAvfed8xSGCkwLr5lurFp9-R838ioTbshJtu0hqDz8KZHBZoZ5hxqn3MX4Ntff6Lo-SIDdvKM51HKIPmRTn-NIMqo-f5jsxs81pbgZLRHoy6aAAAAAIa3EmQAKoGlAAHSD-kqAACsM16AscRn-wIAAAAABFla).
- Excellent job using self-explaining variable names for the most part, often also with explanatory comments. Some of them are a little long, but that's preferable over using abbreviations or insufficiently descriptive names. Some (like `list_of_lists`) could be improved.
- This is pure preference, but in Pandas, I'm a fan of the [`query` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html). E.g.:

  ```
    system_experimental_data = experimental_data.loc[experimental_data['System'] == system]
    system_experimental_data = system_experimental_data[system_experimental_data['Sizes'] != 0]
  ```

  should become (not tested):

  ```
    system_experimental_data = experimental_data.query('System == @system and Sizes != 0')
  ```
- Great, extensive, but not excessive use of comments throughout.

I didn't really dig into what the code's doing or how it's accomplishing that, so I don't know if there may be ways to break the logic up a bit to be cleaner; hopefully these few tips and praises are useful.